# Which class of Jackson library should I use to parse JSON data?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

My JSON data:

```
[  
   "Gi 1/1",
   {  
      "Shutdown":true,
      "Speed":"force10ModeFdx",
      "AdvertiseDisabled":0,
      "MediaType":"dual",
      "FC":"off",
      "MTU":9600,
      "ExcessiveRestart":false,
      "PFC":0
   }
]
```

Controlller class method:

```
public @ResponseBody void setSwitchPortInterfaceInfo(@RequestBody JsonNode jsonNode) 
    throws JsonProcessingException, IOException { }
```

When calling this method only `"Gi 1/1"` got parsed.

Which class do I need to pass as argument to parse complete JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON Data represent in the question is not present in correct format. We need to convert it into proper version than only parse the Same.

Ideal way of declaring JSON structure is:

```
[{"key":"value"},{"key":"value"},{"key":"value"}]
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, i need to make a json-rpc call.remote server only accepting this data. Via curl i am able to get the response. 
So is there any class in jakson library which can parse this json object.

Comment: We can use the ObjectMapper class for conversion

Comment: how can u plz explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

String strToParse = getString(); // put the string you want to parse
JsonNode node = objectMapper.readValue(strToParse, JsonNode.class);
System.out.println(node.get(0)); 
System.out.println(node.get(1));
```

Comment: not working still jsonnode is getting only "Gi 1/1".

Comment: please add some verbal description so that anyone can get you!

Comment: So what happens when you print out jsonNode.toString() to the console ? You should have get the JSON you mentioned. If not there is a problem with passing the JSON to the controller.

Comment: while printing  jsonNode.toString(), only "Gi 1/1" got printed on console. Yes there is a problem in parsing ,How to parse these types of json. Please explain.

Comment: Can we add a string in jsonNode? If yes please explain.

Comment: I think problem here is that you are passing the incomplete JSON to the controller. If you were to pass the right one all the whole data would have been printed not only "Gi 1/1".